# Getting exception with Spring+JPA+DB2 database - org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

I am getting below exception and application get stuck with this error. If I restart the application (server) then it works fine.
I see this error intermittent after 3 or 4 days of interval or something. After restarting application it works fine.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:408)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:532)
    
..
..
..
    
    Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-142, SQLSTATE=42612, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.63.75
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yn.c(yn.java:2644)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yn.d(yn.java:2632)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yn.a(yn.java:2097)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.a(zn.java:7197)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yn.a(yn.java:2073)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.h(cb.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.b(cb.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.i(sb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yn.gb(yn.java:2066)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.pc(zn.java:3446)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.b(zn.java:4236)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.cc(zn.java:720)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.zn.executeQuery(zn.java:694)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 197 common frames omitted
```

Is it related to DB2 dialect or something? I am using dialect - org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect (An SQL dialect for DB2.).

Will it help if I switch the dialect to - org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect (An SQL dialect for DB2/390. This class provides support for DB2 Universal Database for OS/390, also known as DB2/390.)?

DB2 SQL Error Code States that:

```
DB2 SQL-Error: -142
SQLState: 42612
Short Description: THE SQL STATEMENT IS NOT SUPPORTED
An SQL statement was detected that is not supported by the database. The statement might be valid for other IBM relational database products or it might be valid in another context. For example, statements such as VALUES and SIGNAL or RESIGNAL SQLSTATE can appear only in certain contexts, such as in a trigger body or in an SQL Procedure. Additionally, This SQL code will also be issued if a distributed private protocol application uses SQL statements that were implemented after Version 7. DB2 limits the SQL statements that a distributed private protocol application can use to Version 7 or lower SQL statements. See Part 4 of DB2 Application Programming and SQL Guide for more information. System action: The statement cannot be executed. Programmer response: Change the syntax of the SQL statement or remove the statement from the program.
```

Note: I could not see/reproduce this error on local. It's only reproducible on dev/qa/pre-prod environments.

Comment: Check your connection-pool configuration, sometimes it has an SQL statement (data source validation query), and that SQL statement needs to be valid for Db2.  The DBA will also be able to see the SQL statement that is not supported, and the failing statement will appear in log files if you configure SQL tracing.

Comment: Without knowing what statement is failing and what database you are using exactly it's hard to know what is going wrong.